# useReducer, copying previous state property value to another property then resetting said property value

Tags: reactjs

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
 case "Add Details":
return {
   ...state,
   ArrayOfInput: [...state.ArrayOfInput, objectHere]
   objectHere: {
   reset: "",
   after: "",
   copyingTo: "",
   aboveArray: ""
   }
}
default:
 console.log("Please Halp")
}}
```

So trying to copy previous values of object into an array in the state then resetting that object. Getting a not iterable error at the moment

Comment: `[...state.ArrayOfInput, objectHere]` should be `[...state.ArrayOfInput, state.objectHere]`

Comment: Could you please add more detail. On which part/line do you encounter the error? Also, it looks like `objectHere` is not defined when you first use it according to the code you have shown

Comment: Can you please put a screenshot of the error? and can you please be more elaborate and explain what are you trying to achieve by this in your code?